# How can I change the mode of Sqlite Database?

Tags: command-line, database, read-only, sqlite

I want to add some record in my database it is read_only by default, how I can change its mode to add the record.
I want some linux command, I was trying `gfix` but it failed to execute.

Comment: Could you show exactly what you've tried and what it shows you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have write permission to the sqlite file. Then, make sure you have write permission to the directory that the sqlite file is in. This is because SQLite keeps a hidden journal file in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks I check the permissions at the end insert the data via a root.